# The multiplication of two power series

Tags: calculus, power-series

Let R be a real positive number,
$$f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n x^n \\
g(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty b_n x^n
$$
where $|x|<R$.

I have to give the first 4 addends depending on $\{a_n\}$ and $\{b_n\}$.

---

I know that
$$f(x)= a_0 + a_1 x + a_2 x^2 + ... \\
g(x)= b_0 + b_1 x + b_2 x^2 + ...
$$
I've multiplied some elements and I think that I've got the result:
$$f(x)g(x)= a_0b_0+(a_0b_1 + a_1b_0)x+(a_0b_2 + a_1b_1 + a_2b_0)x^2+(a_0b_3 + a_1b_2 + a_2b_1 + a_3b_0)x^3+...$$
But I think that's not the good way to do it, I suppose there is an other better way to do it. Anyway, I don't know if my answer is ok...

Comment: Further to the answer posted by @nala, if power series converges absolutely and so does the product of two power series. Therefore, rearrangement of terms doesn't change the sum of the series.

Comment: An other question, now how can I find the first 4 addends of the Taylor serie of f(x)=(e^x)/(3+2x) in the point x_0=0?

Comment: Write series for $e^x$, which is $1+x +x^2/2!+ x^3/3!+...$ and then for $\frac{1}{1+(2x/3)}$. Multiply them and collect the terms of x with power upto 3 to get first four terms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this kind of product is called the Cauchy product of two series :)
You got the hang of it for the first few terms, now, by induction, it generalizes to:

$\left(\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} a_n x^n\right) \cdot \left(\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} b_n x^n\right) = \displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} c_n x_n$, where each of the $c_n$ is defined as $c_n = \displaystyle\sum_{j = 0}^{n} a_j b_{n-j}$.

This coincides with the first few terms you computed :). You can see more on the [wikipedia page on Cauchy product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_product).

*PS: try to LaTeX your question next time, it makes it clearer to read :)*

Comment: An other question, now how can I find the first 4 addends of the Taylor serie of f(x)=(e^x)/(3+2x)  in the point x_0=0?

Comment: Are you supposed to use a Cauchy product? :) Cause if so, try and see $\frac{1}{3+2x}$ as $\frac{1}{3}\cdot\frac{1}{1 + 2x/3}$, and then expend it as a geometric series :)